# How to set image border for Layout (RelativeLayout) in Android?

Tags: android, border

I want to use border image is below :

[image]
set border for Layout ...?
Should i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /></shape>
```

Save this file in as `customborder.xml` in  `drawbale` folder. In you layout file add this line `android:background="@drawable/customborder"`

Comment: i want to use image (as border, with content image is transparent), not solid color ! Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 9-patch image as apply it as the background. Make the middle transparent and fill the border the way you want.

Here is the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an custom drawable shape that will apply as the background of ImageView which will create a border.

Something like below xml, you can customize it yourself. Put it in drawable/image_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Apply it as ImageView's background. It should create a border for your ImageView.

Comment: image (as border), not solid color ^^

Comment: use a image make border for layout ?

Comment: No, just apply this layout as background for your layout on which you want border.

Answer (score -1):

first create simple border.xml and save in to drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners android:radius="15dip" />
 <solid android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

then after set background of Linear/Relative layout

```
android:background="@drawable/imageee_color"
```